# Register types in UnityContainer to use other named registrations to resolve constructor parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Let's say I have a class that depends on interface `IFace` with several other dependencies injected into constructor (depicted by `...`). I also have 2 implementations of the `IFace` interface.

```cs
class Impl1 : IFace {}
class Impl2 : IFace {}

class Std : IStd {
    Std(IFace impl1, IOtherDependency otherDep, ...) { ... }
}
```

I want to register `Impl1` as the default implementation and register `Impl2` as named implementation which should be injected into certain classes.

```cs
container.RegisterType<IFace, Impl1>();
container.RegisterType<IFace, Impl2>("impl2");
```

Registering `Std` like this would inject the default Impl1 implementation:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IStd, Std>(); // this would inject the default implementation Impl1
```

How can I register `Std` to have the named implementation injected without resorting to calling `Resolve()` manually? The best I could come up with is this:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IStd, Std>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFace>("impl2"), typeof(IOtherDependency, ...)));
```

What I don't like with the above way is that I still need to specify all other constructor parameters; when the signature changes, I need to adjust the registration, the compiler doesn't pick up the problem (runtime exception is thrown) and intellisense doesn't work here.

What I would like to have is something along the lines of: (the `InjectNamedType` is obviously made up)

```cs
container.RegisterType<IStd, Std>(
    InjectNamedType<IFace>(name: "impl2")); // this would tell Unity to look for registration of IFace with that name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
container.RegisterType<IStd>(
    new InjectionFactory(x =>
        x.Resolve<Std>(new DependencyOverride<IFace>(x.Resolve<IFace>("impl2")))));
```

`InjectionFactory` allows you to specify the factory logic that creates the `IStd` object. We use the `Resolve` method to resolve the concrete `Std` class and we use the `DependencyOverride` class to specify which implementation of `IFace` to use. Again we use the `Resolve` method to resolve a specific implementation.

Please note that the factory logic will only run when someone tries to resolve `IStd` (or a class that depends on `IStd`), not when you register `IStd`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: (A short seven years later) Heads up: _'InjectionFactory' is obsolete: 'InjectionFactory has been deprecated and will be removed in next release. Please use IUnityContainer.RegisterFactory(...) method instead.'_ Though [this is very easy to remedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033835/1028230).