# How do you inject the HttpMessageHandler into the HttpClient object using ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient

Without using ASP.NET Core's DI, you can put a ClientHandler which contains a cookie container into the HttpClient object using its constructor, something similar to this:

```
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(uri),
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
            };
```

but when you try to use DI, you don't have the opportunity to call the HttpClient's constructor and pass the handler in. I tried this next line of code:

```
        services.AddHttpClient<HttpClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            });
```

but indeed, it doesn't have a cookie container when you get an instance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by adding a named client instead (which have additional configuration options). We'll simply create a new `HttpClientHandler` with a cookie container:

```
services.AddHttpClient("myServiceClient")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(
        () => new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() }
    );
```

And then you can resolve the client like so:

```
public class MyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    // "myServiceClient" should probably be replaced in both places with a 
    // constant (const) string value to avoid magic strings
    var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("myServiceClient");
}
```

It's also possible to bind the `HttpClient` to the service by supplying a generic parameter to `AddHttpClient`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyService>("myServiceClient") // or services.AddHttpClient<MyServiceInterface, MyServiceImplementation>("myServiceClient")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(
        () => new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() }
    );
```

And then you can simply accept an `HttpClient` in your service:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great apart from the fact tht you're having to 'new' the HttpClientHandler's own dependencies. I have an HttpClientHandler that manipulates authentication for forwarding requests, so I need to inject a TokenService and IHttpContextAccessor into it. How can I do that?

Comment: @Neutrino One of the overloads for `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` takes a `Func<IServiceProvider,HttpMessageHandler>`, so you could resolve your `HttpMessageHandler` from the container (so instead of `() => new ....` you could have `sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MySpecialHandler>();`). If you don't want to new your own handler, you could use a `DelegatingHandler` with [`AddHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.addhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead.

Comment: And how would i access the cookie container from `MyService` in this case?

Comment: But if I didn't want to inject an `HttpClient` and wanted to inject the handler instead? [Reasons](https://methodpoet.com/unit-test-httpclient).

Comment: @ruffin But your goal is to test that the appropriate requests are made using the `HttpClient` and not that dependency injection is working, right? You can still create an `HttpClient` with mocked handlers and inject that instead. That's still compatible with the methods suggested by your link.

Comment: Caught up with how your `public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)` version works with the generic `AddHttpClient`. I'm using Unity for DI, which demands a different setup afacit, but [your idea translates fairly directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776479/1028230). Thank you!